STM32f411CCU6 I2S connection with PCM1808PWR
I've got question about I2S connection of STM32f411CCU6 microcontroller with ADC PCM1808PWR.
I've tried to make project where I check if there is signal output from PCM1808PWR and if so turn on LED (code was generated with chat GPT and project was setup in CubeMX) but I think it has problem with reading values (probably because PCM1808 outputs only 24 bit data format not 16 bit). Wiring isn't a problem, I've double checked it. Master clock is provided from STM32. ADC sampling rate is 48 kHz.
My code is here:


#include "main.h"

I2S_HandleTypeDef hi2s2;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_spi2_rx;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_I2S2_Init(void);

uint8_t audio[6];
uint32_t sample=0;

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_I2S2_Init();
  while (1)
  {
      if(HAL_I2S_Receive_DMA(&hi2s2,(uint16_t*)audio, 3)==HAL_OK)
          {
              sample=((audio[0]<<16))|(audio[1]<<8)|(audio[2]);
              if(sample & 0x800000)
              {
                  sample|=0xFF000000;
              }

              if(sample>0)
              {
                  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              }
              else
              {
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              }
  }
}

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 200;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_I2S2_Init(void)
{
  hi2s2.Instance = SPI2;
  hi2s2.Init.Mode = I2S_MODE_MASTER_RX;
  hi2s2.Init.Standard = I2S_STANDARD_PHILIPS;
  hi2s2.Init.DataFormat = I2S_DATAFORMAT_24B;
  hi2s2.Init.MCLKOutput = I2S_MCLKOUTPUT_ENABLE;
  hi2s2.Init.AudioFreq = I2S_AUDIOFREQ_48K;
  hi2s2.Init.CPOL = I2S_CPOL_LOW;
  hi2s2.Init.ClockSource = I2S_CLOCK_PLL;
  hi2s2.Init.FullDuplexMode = I2S_FULLDUPLEXMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2S_Init(&hi2s2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Stream3_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Stream3_IRQn);

}
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {

  }
}
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{

}
#endif


I've tried another PCM1808PWR in case the one before was damaged but it was not the case, also have tried messing with DMA setup
